# Which is the best place/forum for questions about problems with my IDE?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Visual Studio 2015, rather than programming. Which is the best place to ask such a question?

Comment: Could you post a sample of what your question would look like? It would help to track down the most appropriate site.

Comment: Questions about programming tools are on topic at SO.  Invariably broadly interpreted, whatever is likely to only be answerable by somebody else that is using that tool.  Programmers, SO's target audience.

Comment: Stack Overflow, where I will close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this Well, I probably won't, but it's likely that's your answer.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are not forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you read the ["what I can ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section in the help center you will notice that everything is conditioned to:

> a practical, answerable problem that **is unique to software development**

(bold mine)

So, if your problem with your ide is "how to change the font" or "how to install X IDE on Y", Super User may be the right place for you. Stack Overflow questions would be around the kind of "X ide isn't building my project, says something about incompatible compiler" or "how to integrate my system compiler with my IDE" which are "unique to software development".